# how to place a array[i] items in <img src=""> and <a href=""> tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have an retrieved array items in the var test,

for example :

```
var test = img;
```

Where test[0] holds the value that is grabbed from database as `/images/gallery/1.jpp`

Now i need to place the var test[0] to be place within `img src=""` and a `href=""`, so how can i achieve this?

Comment: How is it that `img` is both an array as well as the element? Your description of the data is unclear to me. If `img src=""` is referring to a different `img` identifier, then is it an element in the DOM? Or a string?

Answer (score 1):

Assign a value to the property "id" of your img and play with its attributes.

```
<img src="" id="image_id_here" width="300" height="400">
<script>document.getElementById('image_id_here').setAttribute('src', test[0]);</script>
```

Assumptions made:

- "test" is an array of strings
- You demand working through a client-sided scripting language such as Javascript to perform front-end operations.

Comment: Your second solution is not going to work. You placed the JavaScript before the image has been loaded into the page. Therefore `document.getElementById('image_id_here')` will be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you need a div tag with the id of `container`:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

You can then use javascript to iterate over the list:

```
  var imgs = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.setAttribute('src', test[i]);
      imgs += img.outerHTML;
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.innerHTML = imgs;
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/T1PGGCQ6QmjeEqDAREI9?p=preview)